# Where is NodeMCU getting ip address from?

Tags: nodemcu

With a blank `init.lua`, whenever I reboot the `NodeMCU`:

```
=wifi.sta.getip()
192.168.1.108   255.255.255.0   192.168.1.1
```

Where is it getting this `192.168.1.108`? 
At one time a couple of weeks ago, I was testing the `wifi` module. 
When it connected it was with this ip.

How can that info be hanging around?
 Or
 is this some sort of internal ip that `NodeMCU` uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the [docs for `wifi.sta.config`](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/wifi/#wifistaconfig):

> Station configuration will be retained until changed even if device is turned off.

So, if you used `wifi.sta.config("ssid", "password")` in the past the device will try to connect to the WiFi "ssid" and obtain an IP (from the DHCP server) whenever it boots.

Comment: like wow! for me this is so counter-intuitive and so against security practices I would have never expected it.

Comment: so what would be the best way to clear this cached ssid / password?

Comment: OK. one can later `wifi.sta.config('nowhere','nowwayjose')`. on rebooting the last attempt is remembered, so `wifi.sta.getip() => nil`

Comment: "so counter-intuitive and so against security practices" - I disagree. Do you store/remember a WiFi password on your laptop? How about your mobile phone? Does it ask you for your home WiFi password every time you enter your apartment/house? It would be a bit cumbersome if you had to hook up the ESP8266 to a serial console just to enter the password upon reboot. You may reset it upon reboot and then [start EUS](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/enduser-setup/) to wirelessly set it up.

Comment: I agree with you. In web development one of my rules of thumb is not to store or cache sensitive information if you can possible get around it. However, in the context of the NodeMCU I think connection caching makes too much sense not to do it - exactly as you said.